# Context of {{title}} in master template when using multiple data/json files using assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I am using assemble.io for a simple static web site but am having issues with the {{title}} tag. Here is a rough overview of the issue.

Here is my **layout.hbs**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- the body tag is used to "pull in" content from pages -->
    {{> body }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I have 2 json files for data:

**foo1.json**

```
{
  "title": "Hello world I am title 1"
}
```

**foo2.json**

```
{
  "title": "I am a different title"
}
```

And I have 2 pages:

**foo1.hbs**

```
{{#foo1 }} 
 {{> module1 }}
 {{> module2 }}
 {{> module3 }}
{{/foo1 }}
```

**foo2.hbs**

```
{{#foo2 }} 
 {{> module1 }}
 {{> module2 }}
 {{> module3 }}
{{/foo2 }}
```

My **gruntfile.js** snippet:

```
options: {
  layout: "src/responsive/layouts/layout.hbs",
  partials: 'src/responsive/modules/**/*.hbs',
  data: 'src/responsive/data/**/*.json',
  flatten: false
},
pages: {
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'src/responsive/pages',
  src: '**/*.hbs',
  dest: 'src/'
}
```

When I run 'grunt assemble' I get no page title. I think this has something to do with context as if I change `{{title}}` in layout.hbs to be `{{foo1.title}}` or `{{foo2.title}}` it works but then both pages get the same title as they share this template.

How can I make the context of `{{title}}` in layout.hbs work for all json files being passed in?

A.

Comment: I have tried {{page.title}} but then both return the title from foo1.json

Comment: I have also tried {{this.page.title}} but again both results return the title from foo1.json. When assemble compiles pages, does it use all concat all the json files and use them for every page? I thought there was a 1-to-1 relationship between page and json if they had the same name?

Comment: Are you sure about `{{page.title}}`? It works correctly for me with your example.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work if i have another index.hbs in a different folder (see below)

Answer (score 3):

@Adi I setup a [repo here](https://github.com/doowb/issue-546) containing the structure that you described.

I just changed [this code in layout.hbs](https://github.com/doowb/issue-546/blob/master/src/responsive/layouts/layout.hbs#L4) and it's working as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{page.title}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- the body tag is used to "pull in" content from pages -->
    {{> body }}
  </body>
</html>
```

If you have a repo we can look at, it might help track down the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can find the repo here:
https://github.com/adrianjacob/assemble-546

If you look at src/index.html and src/insurance/index.html you can see they share the same title after running 'grunt assemble'. However, they should have different titles if you look at the json files.

Cheers,
A.

Comment: Right now, assemble only uses the basename of the files to do the matching. So the second `index` file overwrites the data in the first `index` file. Also, you have `foo.json` in the insurance folder instead of `index.json`. Try changing `insurance/index.hbs` to `insurance/foo.hbs` and you should see the title change.

Comment: So what would you do if you wanted to render an index.html and an insurance/index.html? Is there a plan to do matching based on folders as well?

Comment: I solved that with a Grunt option: buildPages: {
        files: [
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= site.templates %>/',
            src: ['pages/**/*.hbs'],
            dest: '<%= site.dest %>/'
          }
        ]
      }